# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I'm trying to build a Master Detail Page, but I keep getting the error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" and can't test it out. It shows up after I press the login button to move onto the home page (I'll attach screenshots) but obviously the screen just stays on the home page.

Code: XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                  x:Class="RoseySports.Home">





            <MasterDetailPage.Master>

        <ContentPage> 
            <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">



        <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Create Activity" TextColor="White" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
            <Button Text="Check Availability" TextColor="White"/>
            <Button Text="Check Invitations" TextColor="White"/>
            <Button x:Name="SMA" Text="Propose Saturday  Morning Activity" TextColor="White"/>
            <Button x:Name="Logout" Text="Logout" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_1" TextColor="White" Margin="20"/>
        </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ContentPage>
                </MasterDetailPage.Master>


            <MasterDetailPage.Detail>

            <ContentPage>

        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
            Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">

                    <ContentView Padding="10,40,10,10">
        <Button Text="Menu" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_2"/>
                        </ContentView>

        </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>


        </ContentPage>

            </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Code: C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace RoseySports
{
    public partial class Home : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Detail = new Create_Activity();
            IsPresented = false;
        }

        private async void Handle_Clicked_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Login_Page());
        }

        void Handle_Clicked_2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            IsPresented = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WszjT.jpg)[Page before error shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD1qW.png)

Comment: The relevant information should be in the inner exception of the TargetInvocationException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `ContentPage` `Title`.

First you should turn on the Xaml compiler to aid in catching XAML problems (at compile time and/or better errors messages without looking through the inner exceptions of TargetInvocationException).

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

re: [XAML Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc)

While the compiler will not actually catch this missing title attribute at build time, you will get the error message at run time:

```
`Title property must be set on Master page`
```

So, set the title on your ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage Title="Some Page Title">
```

Example:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Some Page Title">
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
            <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="Create Activity" TextColor="White" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Check Availability" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Button Text="Check Invitations" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Button x:Name="SMA" Text="Propose Saturday  Morning Activity" TextColor="White"/>
                    <Button x:Name="Logout" Text="Logout" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_1" TextColor="White" Margin="20"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <ContentPage>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" Source="background.jpg" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
                <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1">
                    <ContentView Padding="10,40,10,10">
                        <Button Text="Menu" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" TextColor="White" Clicked="Handle_Clicked_2"/>
                    </ContentView>
                </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Do you know why this is? I lost hours on this issue and was getting so desperate I was just trying anything I read.
Why is defining a title so important? Anyway, thank you very much for this!

Comment: @AsPas I've never been through *all* that related code, but the exception is thrown really early (before any native controls are created) and would *assume* it is related to Android's ActionBar and trying to set its title to a `null` would be a "late" exception and instead of peppering the code w/ if/else statements to test for `null`, it is simpler to just test it once for all platforms and then assume that is it is never `null` in later code (ie. a fail early vs. fail late coding style)